# вопрос про Текстурные координаты и индексы(Связано с FBX)

Tags: opengl, fbx

изучая openGL столкнулся с такой проблемой что UVIndex отличается PolygonVertexIndex в fbx и по этому текстура не правильно накладывается.
(в 3d max выбирал unwrap UVW после конвертировал в mesh)(пишу код на java по этому не могу использовать fbx sdk)

PolygonVertexIndex: *18 {

a: 0,2,3,3,1,0,**0**,**1**,4,**1**,3,4,3,2,4,2,**0**,4

UVIndex: *18 {

a: 0,2,3,3,1,0,**6**,**7**,4,**7**,3,4,3,2,4,2,**5**,4

некоторые Vn не сходятся(выделенные жирным и по этому текстура не правильно накладывается) не могу решить проблему

Comment: Нужно руками парсить и дублировать такие вертексы. Это иногда называется discontinuous UVs.

Comment: @Kromster есть ли уроки по этому поводу?